# How to cache compiled webassembly modules?

Tags: caching, browser, webassembly

I am creating a CAD web app using OpenCascade.js a port of the OpenCascade CAD library to JavaScript and WebAssembly via Emscripten.

The wasm file is cached by browser but every time the page is reloaded module is recompiled and it takes good 10 seconds. I would like to cache the compiled module to avoid this unnecessary recompilation step.

I tried researching a way to cache the compiled module, but support for using Indexed DB is dropped at least from Firefox:
https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/WebAssembly/Caching_modules

Apparently Chrome's V8 has support for caching when using streaming API:
https://v8.dev/blog/wasm-code-caching

but I would be interested if there is some way of caching that would work on Chromium based browsers as well as in Firefox