# Ca I persist webassembly app that was downloaded by the browser?

Tags: c#, webassembly

If I have a webassembly app - can I persist it in the browser local storage, local files or elsewhere? Why does it need to be downloaded again and again?

Comment: You have a client and server.  So every time the server changes you need to download the changes to the client.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536562/how-to-cache-compiled-webassembly-modules

Comment: hmm. Perhaps my question is a duplicate, but it was not answered there. 
Regarding changes if my webassembly changes - I can always have a version# as data exchange via rest api.